# SSRS - Changing the reference of element expressions to reflect dataset rename automatically

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am using the SQL Server Report Builder, and just changed the name of a dataset. Is there a way to make all the already existing elements in the report that reference the old name, to use the new name?

Doing each one manually is a lot of work, so any tips would be appreciated!

To do each field manually, I would have to enter the expression and change

```
=First(Fields!FieldName.Value, "OldDataSetName")
```

to:

```
=First(Fields!FieldName.Value, "NewDataSetName")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your report is just an XML file. Open it in notepad and replace all occurrences of old name to new.